# Switch one fragment to another inside scrollview

Tags: android

I have a scroll view inside which there is a fragment and when i click on a button I want to switch fragment to another one.
I tried Fragment Transaction but I am getting this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Code :

```
Search search = new Search();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.scrollView,search).commit();
```

Comment: Can you post your xml file containing scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a FrameLayout as your ScrollView's child and then use the transaction to change the fragment

**xml(*partial*):**

```
<ScrollView>
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"/>
</ScrollView>
```

and then with java

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout,new Search()).commit();
```